# How is it $ S = (a,b)∪(c,d)$

Tags: real-analysis

I was solving supermum and infimum.
The question was:
[image] 
But I can't understand how is
$S = (a,b)∪(c,d)$.

Please explain.Thank you.

Comment: Start: Figure out the signs of $x-a$, $x-b$, $x-c$, $x-d$ based on when $x$ is in the intervals $(-\infty,a)$, $(a,b)$, $(b,c)$, $(c,d)$, $(d,\infty)$ separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x \in S$ if and only if either $1$ or $3$ of the terms $x - a$, $x - b$, $x - c$, $x - d$ are negative and the others are positive.. If $x < a$ or $x > d$, then none or all four terms are negative, so $x \notin S$. If $b < x < c$, then exactly two of the terms are negative, and the expression is positive.

If $x \in (a, b) \cup (c, d)$, the expression is negative, and if $x \in \{a, b, c, d\}$, the expression is zero.